# Can't execute uuid_generate_v5

Tags: postgresql

After installing extension uuid-ossp successfully I cannot execute the uuid_generate_v5 function.  Always barks about not existing or bad argument types.

select uuid_generate_v5(uuid('40f209ac-33f7-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125'), cast('1234' as text));

Outputs:
uuid_generate_v5(uuid, text)
ERROR: function uuid_generate_v5(uuid, text) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

select * from pg_proc where proname= 'uuid_generate_v5'; show that the function does exist, I must be using it wrong somehow but the arg types are correct per the documented function and the source code...

PostgreSQL 11.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit

Comment: `function uuid_generate_v5(unknown, text) does not exist ... No function matches the given ... argument types.` Are the argument types really `unknown` and `text`?

Comment: Anyway works for me with pgsql 9.6 https://rextester.com/WUAS9012

Comment: Sorry no, it is uuid_generate_v5(uuid, text) - I updated the question correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension (and hence the function) is installed in a schema that is not on your `search_path`.

Try

```
\dx "uuid-ossp"
```

This will show you the schema where the extension is installed.

Either include the schema qualification in the function name:

```
SELECT extschema.uuid_generate_v5('40f209ac-33f7-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125', '1234');
```

or add the extension schema to the `search_path`.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.